# Define a global ready function for every page in WinJS

Tags: winjs

My WinJS app uses the single navigation model. There is some common code that I would like to apply to every page in the app. Instead of placing the code in each page's ready function, I would like to be able to able to define a "global" ready function that will be executed when a page's ready event is fired. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can define a Mixin object with utility function used for all pages.

```
utils.js:
PageMixin = {
        ready: function ready(element, options)
        {
            this.element = element;
            this.options = options;
            this.initialize();
            this.onready();
        },
        initialize: function initialize()
        {
            // write common initialize code here
        }
    };

page.js:
var Page = WinJS.UI.Pages.define('/pages/mypage/page.html',
    {
        onready: function onready()
        {
             // page specific initialization code here
        }
    });

// this will make all PageMixin util methods available on Page. 
WinJS.Class.mix(Page, PageMixin);
```

refer [WinJS.Class.mixin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229836.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a util method setup similarly. However, I would like to have all ready functions on each page automatically call initialize without having to modify every page in my app.

Comment: updated answer based on this. wait a minute. this still requires changing all existing pages.

Comment: this still requires changing all existing pages. but each page `onready()` will not have to call `this.initialize`. one time rename of all ready methods will be reqd.